# Magento2 Rest api without any module

Tags: magento2, rest-api, webapi

I am new to Magento and I am having an issue with the use of the rest API.

I see some blogs/tutorials on the Internet where they create modules to use the web API.
Also in magento2 API doc, they tell to create the webapi.xml file but it is not cleared/told that the file should be in a module or where exactly.

My question is do we need a module to use the Rest API?
I didn't find out also the webapi.xml doc.

Btw I need the API to create new products in the store. I am using API of a website which gives me the images and name of products.

Comment: if you want to create your own api then you have to create `webapi.xml` but if you want to use magento's default then you can check this official doc. https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/

Comment: for creating a `webapi.xml`  you need to create a new module right?

Comment: yes in Vendor\Module\etc\webapi.xml and define your api and endpoint and class and method

Comment: ok thanks, the first comment has answered my question. Could you tell me please also  If I want to create new product and want to use the Magento's default api https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/ then which route or URL or whatever should I choose among?

Comment: `catalogProductRepositoryV1` and chose post method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85228/discussion-between-phoenix404-and-rakesh-varma).

Comment: @Phoenix404 did you got your answer ?